# Using map or foreach for doing summation in Netlogo?

Tags: list, sum, netlogo

Hello i have the next code:

```
 to difusion-out
   if any? turtles with [color = yellow and shape = "ai"]
   [ 
    let mylist (list ([autoinduc] of turtles with [shape = "circle 2" and    color = yellow]))
    let mylist2 (list count turtles with [shape = "ai"])
    let mylist3 (map [?1 - ?2] (mylist) (mylist2))
    let mylist4 sum (mylist3) 
    let concentracion-se ((- kse * count turtles with [shape = "ai"] ) + ( 2 * (mylist4)))
    ask one-of turtles with [shape = "ai"]
     [hatch concentracion-se
    ]
    ] 
 end
```

What i m trying to do is substract each one of the members of mylist  each one of the members of mylist2 so this new list named mylist3, need to sum all of the member using the command sum. But when running the procedure i get this error: - expected input to be a number but got the list [0] instead.
error while observer running -
So what can be the problem? I´m not defining well my lists, or the map command is not correctly used?

Answer (score 1):

The `map` looks fine to me. You're setting up your lists wrong:

```
let mylist (list ([autoinduc] of turtles with [shape = "circle 2" and    color = yellow]))
```

`[autoinduc] of turtles with [shape = "circle 2" and color = yellow]` returns a list of the turtles' `autoinduc`. When you put `list` in front of it, that sticks the entire list in *another* list. So you end up with `[[1 2 3]]` instead of `[1 2 3]`.

I think this is also wrong:

```
let mylist2 (list count turtles with [shape = "ai"])
```

`count turtles with [shape = "ai"]` returns a number (the number of turtles with that shape). Putting `list` in front of it sticks that single number in a list. So you just end up with a list of a single number, which is probably not what you want.